# What is the chance of a pristine Archaeology solve in Mists?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just heard about [pristine solves](http://www.wowhead.com/news=205467/mists-of-pandaria-new-archaeology-solves-news-round-up), acting as quest items to encourage the archaeology grind.  From that link, their summary is:

> A new type of artifact is added in Mists of Pandaria--pristine solves. These solves are enhanced versions of common-quality solves. Completing them will create a quest item, which can be turned in to the Lorewalkers and displayed in their museum. **The chance for creating a pristine version of an artifact instead of a common one is completely random.**

Obviously random == "has some percentage chance".  Has the chance of a pristine solve been discovered/calculated?

Comment: Anything right now will most likely be a rough estimate. Until people upload a lot of data to Wowhead once it's live or if Blizz puts up the approximate drop rate on their own database, it's a crapshoot.

Comment: It's quite reasonable for the question to remain unanswered until the information becomes available. :)

Comment: Not sure on the 'chance', but so far from casual surveying while doing Cloud Serpent dailies I have completed 3 rares - the polearm, the umbrella off hand and the anatomical dummy.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Are you including any non-Pandaria artifacts in those numbers? The 9 rare solves makes me think you have, because there are only 4 Pandaria rares, and you can't solve a rare more than once per character. Perhaps you're looking at the total number of *unique* artifacts?

Comment: In case anyone is still curious about this, this question is practically unanswerable. Blizzard does not release this data. A player can only complete each unique pristine artifact once, and there are less than 30 of them. In order to gather reliable data, a player would need to find these pristine artifacts across many characters and track the percentage for them, which is extremely unlikely and unnecessary for someone to do.

Answer (score 3):

My calculations show it to be about 10%

I have only 2 that weren't pristine at 20 collections (one still only at 15 collects) - if you do the probability permutation it shows 88% should be pristine by the time you get 20 of them.  This jives with what I have so far.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you could supply an official resource.

Comment: To my knowledge, Blizzard do not reveal such numbers.